# Sending email works via Thunderbird but not blat. Any ideas why?

Tags: blat

I can send an email using Thunderbird.  I use the same smtp server address when installing blat.  But, blat does not send the email.  I get the following error:

```
Error:  Server refused connection.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: This happens within cygwin on a Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may trying to use a regular connect rather than an http**s** connection.  Or you may be useing the regular 80 port rather than the SSL port 443 (or something like that).

Comment: It looks like the email in Thunderbird is being sent using Extended SMTP.  But, why would the smtp server accept that email and not an email with simply SMTP.  Is there a major difference between the two?

Comment: Yes, if you are not using the correct ports for encrypted/non-encrypted.